# Computing $\frac{d^6 f}{dx^6}(0)$ where $f(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{x^2}{5}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Using
$$\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\ldots$$
I know that we can plug $\frac{x^2}{5}$ in for every $x$, to get $\frac{x^2}{5}-(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{x^2}{5})^3+\cdots$, but I need help finding what $f^{(6)}(0)$ is equal to.

Comment: If you mean $f^{(6)}(0)$ then it's related to the $x^6$-coefficient in the power series.

Answer (score 1):

Having shown that the $x^6$ coefficient of $\tan^{-1}\frac{x^2}5$ is $-\frac1{375}$, note that taking one derivative will multiply the coefficient by $6$, taking the second multiplies it by $5$ and so on. Eventually you are left with a constant term at the $6$th derivative that is $6!$ times the original coefficient, or $-\frac{48}{25}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\arctan \left (\frac {x^2}{5} \right)=\frac{x^2}{5}-\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{x^2}{5} \right)^3+\frac{1}{5} \left(\frac{x^2}{5} \right)^5-\cdots$$
$$f^{(6)}(x)=0-\frac{1}{3}\frac{6!}{5^3} +\frac{1}{5} \frac{10!x^4}{4!5^5} -\cdots$$
Then you have that: $$f^{(6)}(0)=-\frac  {6!}{3.5^3}=-\frac {48}{25}$$